# Visual Studio 2015 Node.js Tools - Cannot install mongodb 2.x package - 260 filename length

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-2015

Node.js Tools for visual studio 2015 look very promising for node.js/typescript development in a team already using visual studio and azure.
However, the [known limitation of 260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807281/visual-studio-pathtoolongexception-even-when-the-path-length-is-less-than-260) in solution file path is getting into the way of using the Node Package Manager. 
I am just failing to build a very simple node/mongo api just because the modules filepaths get too long. Folks at microsoft let this problem open and send you [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation) for troubleshooting. Any known work around?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I found an ugly looking answer that works using the module "flatten-packages".

while being in root folder:

```
> npm install - g flatten-packages
> flatten-packages
```

your npm dependencies will look horrible... a long list.. but it works.

More discussions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/69.).

It will be great if somebody can find a better way.